# Generating unitriangular matrices in Octave|MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave, triangular

I have a very simple question, I am struggling to find an answer to. I would like to craft (upper or lower) unitriangular and unitrapezoidal matrices in Octave. Is there an efficient and elegant way to achieve that?

Let, `A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]`. I can obtain upper or lower triangular matrix `B` with `B = triu(A)` and `B = tril(A)`. Consider a lower triangular case `B = tril(A)`. To extract the elements below the main diagonal I use `B = tril(A,-1)`. That will result in

```
0   0   0
4   0   0
7   8   0
```

But how to obtain ones on the main diagonal of `B` now? One workaround that I have is generating an identity matrix and adding it to `B`:

```
B = tril(A,-1) + eye(size(A))

1   0   0
4   1   0
7   8   1
```

But I feel this is suboptimal due to the addition. Is there a better way?

Comment: I think your solution is 1) elegant 2) clear. If you are worried about computational time, I am almost sure this is not the bottleneck. "Early optimization is the root of all evil"

Comment: Identity (and generally diagonal) matrix in Octave is internally implemented as a special compact matrix with efficient operations. However these solutions may be slightly more efficient: `B = tril(A,-1); B+=eye(size(A));` or `B = tril(A,-1); B(1:size(A,1)+1:end) = 1;`